# Send xsl doc in body of email

Tags: c#, xslt, email

Programming would be much easier without users...

What I really need to be able to do is:
Put the content of a web page (including styles) into the body of an email and also set the subject.
OR
Send the current user an email containing the body of a web page.

I really don't care how this is implemented -- server or client side.  I've not come up with any good way of client side besides trying to push the web page into the clipboard for the users to then paste into their email.

**App Background**
I wrote a web site using c#, ts, angular.  The site manages xml documents.

The users can select a document and click the "Human Readable" button or the "XML" button.  The "Human Readable" is xml with xsl to make it look pretty for the humans.  The XML button is apparently for non-humans.

The "Human Readable" version opens in another browser tab.

The users want a new "email" button for emailing the human readable.  The person clicking the email button has access to my web site but the recipient may not.

I've attempted educating my users to do Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, open email, Ctrl+V but this is beyond most of their capabilities.

I have tried so many different ways to accomplish this and all have failed.

I currently do a mailto link which opens their email and the body contains a link to the Human Readable.

Here's what I've tried so far -- this may not be a conclusive list of my attempts as I've been at this for a few days now.

1. I've tried putting a button in the human readable (xsl with javascript) in an attempt to copy the resulting html into the clipboard for the users to paste.
2. A button on the web site to scrape an iFrame into the clipboard
3. Many iterations of javascript copy/paste techniques
4. a c# controller that does a ReadAsStringAsync().Result function (which I will post below because I like that solution the best so far...

Option #4 I'm partial to and I got almost working -- if it weren't for that pesky xsl not getting formatted it would probably work.  My results are the data being presented without xml tags and no styles.

```
[ActionName("PostEmailHumanReadable")]
    public void EmailHumanReadable(List<DocumentVM> documents)
    {
        foreach (var document in documents)
        {

            var docId = document.document.DocId;
            var docTypeId = document.document.DocTypeId;
            var co = string.Empty;
            var order = string.Empty;
            var name = string.Empty;
            var po = string.Empty;

            // get the data for the subject line
            using (var efUoW = new EFUnitOfWork(EDIEnvironment.EDIEnvironment.Instance.ConnectionString))
            {
                var doc = efUoW.DocumentRepository.GetById(docId);
                co = doc.CompanyId.ToString();
                var orders = efUoW.DocumentOrderRepository.GetByDocumentID(docId).ToList();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.Source_Order))
                        order = doc.Source_Order;
                    else
                        order = "n/a";


                foreach (var o in orders)
                    order += string.Format("{0} ", o.OrderId);
                //order = string.Join(",", doc.DocumentOrders.Select(q => q.OrderId).ToList());
                name = doc.BillToName;
                name = doc.PurchaseOrder;
            }
            var subject = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", co, order, name, po);

            // get the human readable
            var hrResponse = GetFile(docId, docTypeId);
            var hrText = hrResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // format the url
            var url = string.Format("<a href='/api/Documents/Getfile?DocId={0}&DocTypeId={1}'>click here to open the jEDI Human Readable</a><br><br>", docId, docTypeId);

            // find the current user's email address
            var users = new List<string>();
            users.Add(AppUser.ADUserName);
            //var to = EmailUtility.GetEmailID(users);

            // and finally send the email
            EmailUtility.SendEmail(EmailUtility.GetEmailID(users), null, subject, url + hrText);
        }
    }
    [ActionName("GetFile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(int DocId, int DocTypeId)
    {
        if (DocTypeId == (int)DocumentTypeEnum.EDI850)
        {
            using (var efUoW = new Factory_UOW().EF_UOW())
            {
                var doc = efUoW.DocumentRepository.GetById(DocId);
                var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(doc.Message);
                var proc = new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='/EDI850.xsl'");
                xdoc.Root.AddBeforeSelf(proc);
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(xdoc.ToString());
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
                response.Content.Headers.Add("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
                return response;
            }
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance in getting this to work.
And, yes, I know I shouldn't do the Async().Result -- blocking and all that... Let's just get this working first, shall we?

Comment: Have you considered doing the XSLT transform on the server, and then just emailing the HTML? Have a read up on xslcompiledtransform at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That worked nicely.  If you post that as an answer I'll mark that as the answer.  The only problem I'm having now is that not all styles are showing in the email.  If I view source, save it as html, and view it in a browser it looks fine.

Comment: Email clients are not browsers. Depending on their email clients HTML/CSS formatting features (often limited) users will see different results. Quickly I come up with this options. Deliver a text only representation, an almost text only (use only basic html features like <i>, <strong><table>...) version, a PDF or a link to a web page (if this is an option).

Comment: Outlook wasn't using my css so I put it into a style attribute which fixed the problem.